# How to verifiy if IP is used by particular server or not using Shell script?

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to run a Shell script which fails at grep state, below is what I am running

```
activeIP=`grep -Po '(?<=active.server.ip=).*' /etc/active.properties`

command="ifconfig | grep "$activeIP

eval "$command"

if [ $? == 0 ]; then
    echo"You are on Active"
else
    echo"You are not on Active"
fi
```

## active.properties file contents:

```
active.server.ip=10.25.15.1
standby.server.ip=10.25.15.2
```

Please help......

Answer (score 0):

I would use a different tool for parsing the file, and also I'd avoid the `eval` since it's so easy to go wrong with that.  So using `awk`, and assuming you're using `bash` I'd do it like:

```
activeIP=$(awk -F= '$1 == "active.server.ip" {print $2}' /etc/active.properties)
if ip addr show | grep -qw "$activeIP"; then
    echo "You are on Active"
else
    echo "You are not on Active"
fi
```

### Explanation:

First we use `awk` with `-F=` to split fields on `=`.  Then if the first field is equal to `active.server.ip` we'll print the second field.  Note, if you have/allow whitespace around the `=` this will need to be changed a bit.  We store that printed value in `activeIP` just as you did in your attempt.

Next, we check if the given IP shows up in our current IP list.  The `ip` command is the newer version of `ifconfig`, so I swapped for that.  There's no need to build a string and `eval` it because bash will already do variable substitution as when it's executing the command.

We'll use `grep` to check the output of the `ip addr show` command, and we add the `-w` to match words, so if our IP is a substring of another IP it won't match (e.g., the string `192.168.114.3` will not match the IP `192.168.114.37`).  Also, since we don't actually care about the matching line, I added `-q` to make it run quietly.

Finally, `if` will look at the exit status already, so we don't have to do an explicit test for `$?`.

As another possible step reduction, we could actually skip storing the IP in a variable and let `bash` do process substitution for us like so:

```
if ip addr show | grep -qw $(awk -F= '$1 == "active.server.ip" {print $2}' /etc/active.properties); then
    echo "You are on Active"
else
    echo "You are not on Active"
fi
```

So it will do the `awk` "in line" as it were.

Comment: Thank you Eric, but that doesn't work either, When I run the same script from server which does not have IP output still returns Active Server, while file is same.

Comment: I'd, then, recommend adding `set -x` to the script to see more verbosely what it's doing, changing your IPs to match or not what are on my machine I see the expected output for when there is or is not a match

Comment: Ahh, Now I understand where issue was, Thank you Eric. Here is the issue
+ grep -qw $'10.25.15..1\r'
There is a carriage returned. The first script works fine as well. Your explanation helped a lot :)